# SQLite Int to Hex and Hex to Int in query

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sqlite

I have some numeric data that is given to me in `INTEGER` form. I insert it along with other data into SQLite but when I write it out The `INTEGER` Numbers need to be 8 digit `Hex` Numbers with leading zeros.

### Ex.

**Input**

```
400 
800 
25 
76
```

**Output**

```
00000190 
00000320 
00000019 
0000004C
```

Originally I was converting them as I read them in and storing them as `TEXT` like this.

```cpp
stringstream temp;
temp << right << setw(8) << setfill('0') << hex << uppercase << VALUE;
```

But life is never easy and now I have to create a second output in `INTEGER` form not `HEX`. Is there a way to convert `INTEGER` numbers to `HEX` or `HEX` numbers to `INTEGERS` in SQLite?

I'd like to avoid using C++ to change data after it is in SQLite because I've written a few convent export functions that take a queries result and print them to a file. If I need to touch the data during the queries return I couldn't use them.

I've looked at the `HEX()` function in SQLite but that didn't have desired results. Could I make a function or would that be very inefficient? I'm doing this over a really big data set so anything expensive should be avoided.

Note:
I'm using SQLites C/C++ interface with Visual Studios 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well not my favorite answer I've decided to add a column in the table that is the INTEGER value.

If someone finds a better way to do this I'm all ears.

**EDIT:**

After Implementing this answer and looking at it's effect on the program this appears to be a really good way to get the data without adding much to the run time load. This answer does add to the size of the Database a little but it doesn't require any extra processing to get the values from SQLite because this is just grabbing a different column in the query.

Also because I had these values to start with, this answer had a **HUGE** cost savings by adding them to the table verses processing later to get values I through away earlier in the program.

Answer (score 23):

You can use sqlite3 printf() function:

```
CREATE TABLE T (V integer);
insert into T(V) values(400), (800), (25), (76);
select printf('%08X', V) from T;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sqlite3_create_function`. See an [example](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/readme_sqlite_tutorial.html)